# How to call a method when a jsp web application starts on tomcat server?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

Having a jsp web application on a tomcat server, how can I call one of my java methods when the server starts? I mean without opening the website using a navigator... just doing it when the server starts, for example, after a reboot of the server I want to start some jobs, without entering the website, just automatically when teh server reboots and the jsp web application is loaded by tomcat.

How can I do that?

Can't find any info about that

Comment: implement ServletContextListener

Comment: ok thank you but one question more. The "start" function of my web app is not static because it's called by jersey using a url scheme. I need to call that start method, but as it is not static, I can't call it. Can that function be static and work with jersey?

Comment: *but as it is not static, I can't call it* **not** understanding you, can you not instantiate an Object?

Comment: The jersey method is not static, because it uses objects with instances. If i put it static, i'm getting this exception: No enclosing instance of type is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of)

Comment: Please ask a separate question if you have a separate question. This one has already been answered by @ScaryWombat.